# How to fix structured data error "Missing: updated" and "Missing: author" for Blogger blog?

Tags: html, blogger, microformats, google-search-console

Google Search Console structured data for my Blogger blog Narayankripa shows error in hathom (markup: microformats.org) `Missing: updated` error for 220 pages.

Live Data for the latest error page: [Live testing tool results](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?url=https://www.narayankripa.com/2018/07/eight-years-of-blessed-mission-narayankripa.html#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.narayankripa.com%2F2018%2F07%2Feight-years-of-blessed-mission-narayankripa.html)

The second error `Missing: author` is for 11 items which are all blog pages. The pages with the `Missing: author` error also have `Missing: updated` error.

Live data for one page: [Live Testing tool results](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?url=https://www.narayankripa.com/p/blog-testimonials.html#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.narayankripa.com%2Fp%2Fblog-testimonials.html)

Comment: Please post your code here and detail what you have attempted to rectify these issues.

Comment: @DKyleo Haven't done any changes.

Comment: @mohinip attach your blogger template HTML to your question

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh I've added the code here.

Comment: You cannot insert code in the question directly because stackoverflow.com striping tags, you have to wrap it in Code Sample from tools or upload it here : https://pastebin.com/ and send the generated link in comment.

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh https://pastebin.com/GcMb2nL5 hatom link. https://pastebin.com/GcMb2nL5

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh html code link. https://pastebin.com/Bxkr2RvN